# Magento 2 bin/magento command prompting php version message

Tags: php, server, development-environment, mamp-pro

I'm running Magento 2 on MAMP Pro local dev server (mac osx). I have site installed and running fine.

If I try to run following command in site root in terminal, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` I get following message:

> Magento supports PHP 5.5.0 or later. Please read
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

MAMP Pro appears to support multiple PHP versions, one of which is 5.5.9.

Try switching your version as shown in the screenshot below, restarting MAMP, and try the command again:

[image: MAMP Pro screenshot]

I'm not sure if this will affect the version of PHP you're using on the command line, but give it a shot and go from there.